# Expressing where domain of two variable is continuous. Set notation form.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function $$f(x,y)={1\over{y-x^2}}$$ And it is very obvious that this is not continuous when $x=0\;\;y=0\;\;\;and\;\;\;x=1\;\;y=1$ but I'm having trouble remembering how to express this in set notation form. I'm wondering if it is obvious to anyone else.

Here is what I have: $$D: \left.\right\lbrace {(x,y)|(x,y)\neq(0,0),\;(x,y)\neq(1,1)} \left.\right\rbrace$$

I'm not used to these two variable functions yet.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are other points too : for example, $(2,4)$ etc. so you need to find exactly, the set of discontinuity, and that happens precisely when $y = x^2$.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Ah! I missed that! Then this would be correct: $$\left.\right\lbrace {(x,y)|y\neq x^2} \left.\right\rbrace$$ no?

Comment: Right, I expect that to be the domain of continuity of the given function. In particular, it is also the domain of the function i.e. where it is well defined.